# If $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed, then $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{k})S=S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Based on the comment I edited the question.*

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded symmetric convex set.

Question: How to show that if $S$ is closed, then $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{k})S$ is equal to $S$.

I do not know how to use the closed property to prove this lemma.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If $k\in\Bbb N$, what is $\left(1+\frac1k\right)S$? Is it $\left\{\left(1+\frac1k\right)x\,\middle|\,x\in S\right\}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By the text book it is expansion of $S$. [page 309](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441926746). You right.

Comment: I don't understand. Why does this even contain $S$? Let $S = \{1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^1$, then this is certainly closed, but the intersection you are asking for is the intersection over all sets $\{1 + \frac{1}{k}\}$, which is certainly empty.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In fact, I am reading the Minkowski Theorem in lattices.

Comment: If you're reading Minkowski's Theorem, maybe there are missing hypotheses on $S$? Like, I suppose, $S$ being symmetric about the origin and convex.

Comment: @BastiaanCnossen Based on your comment I edited the question. As I said in the last comment I am reading the Minkowski Theorem in lattices from [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441926746)

Comment: @Fimpellizieri You are right. I made a mistake in writing  hypotheses and because of this I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. It's easy to see that $S\subset (1+\frac1k)S$ for all $k$, so that $S$ is contained in the intersection. Now, what have you tried? Take some $x\not\in S$ and and suppose it belonged in the intersection...

Comment: @Fimpellizieri My problem with this question is right here. I do not know what problem make happen if the $S$ is not a closed set.

Comment: @user0410 Suppose $S= (-1,1)$, i.e. $S$ is open. Note that $1 \in (1+1/k)S=(-1-1/k,1+1/k)$ for all $k$, however $1\notin S$.

Comment: @Surb Thanks I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is nonempty, symmetric about the origin and convex, then it's easy to see that $0\in S$.
Now, if $U$ is convex and $0\in U$, then $U \subset \alpha U$ for all $\alpha\geqslant 1$, so clearly $S$ is contained in the intersection (regardless of $S$ being closed).

On the other hand, if $x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{k})S$, then $x\in (1+\frac{1}{k})S$ for each $k\geqslant 1$.
This means that for each $k\geqslant 1$ there is some $x_k \in S$ with $x = (1+\frac1k)x_k$.

In other words, the sequence $(x_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ given by

$$x_k = \left(\frac 1{1+\frac1k}\right)x = \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)x$$

lies in $S$.
Now, does this sequence converge? And if $S$ is closed, what else can you say...?

Comment: This  sequence converge to $x$ and also $(x_k)\neq x $ for $k>0$. Hence, $x$ is a limited point of $S$. More, $S$ is a close set and because of this $S$ has its limited points.Therefore, $x$ is an element of $S$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. If $(x_k)$ is a convergent sequence in a closed set $X$, then the limit of the sequence also lies in $X$.